# Python says a specific item is in a list that is empty

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a hangman game. I have a feature that says if the letter that you chose is in a list of all the letters guessed, it will tell you that it has already been guessed. When i run the program it says that the letter has been guessed even though it hasn't been guessed or if it's the first letter that i guessed.

```
import random
print("---Hangman---")
WordList = ["programming", "computer", "game"]
LetterList = []
Word = random.choice(WordList)
NumberOfLetters = len(Word)
print("There are", NumberOfLetters, "letters in the word.")


for i in range (NumberOfLetters):
    print("Guess a letter:")
    LetterGuess = input()
    LetterList.append(LetterGuess)
    if LetterGuess in LetterList:
        print("You already guessed that letter")
    elif LetterGuess in Word:
        print("Correct")
        print("You now have the correct letters: ", LetterList)
        i += 1
    elif LetterGuess not in Word:
        print("Wrong")
        print("You have the correct letters: ", LetterList)
```

When i guess a number it says this:

```
 ---Hangman---
There are 11 letters in the word.
Guess a letter:
d
You already guessed that letter
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the guess to the list, then immediately check whether it is there.

```
LetterList.append(LetterGuess)
if LetterGuess in LetterList:
```